# Bluetooth doesn't work in ASUS X550L

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth

I have an ASUS X550L pc running Ubuntu 14.04

The bluetooth doesnt work and stops scanning after about 20secs with no devices found. And the device is not found too even though its set to discoverable.

I tried several thing but didn't get fix.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13ee:0001 MosArt 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: So what OS are you using? The title says 14.04, a tag says 12.04, and the bluetooth name is mint-0 which would indicate it is Linux Mint? I can probably make a dkms package that will fix the issue and the issue is that the current 3.13.0-43 kernel doesn't support the device.  The bluetooth device is an Atheros AR3012 that requires firmware and it needs the ath3k module to load the firmware.  You can install the firmware with `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware` and if you can boot with kernel 3.13.0-39, http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=181629#p944725 will fix

Comment: Sorry It's 14.04

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1395465) for your "13d3:3408 IMC Networks" Bluetooth controller.

And the fix for it will be release in 14.10 Utopic soon (3.16 kernel), it looks like that patch won't be backported to 14.04 Trusty (3.13 kernel) thus there are 3 possible solutions:

1. There is a 3.16 test kernel provided by *Pilot6 (hanipouspilot)* from comment #20 on that report:
   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07642x3lziqgmz9/AACGWNO5_lNnX7x7tYMoH9gka?dl=0

   Please download the .deb files to a certain directory and run the following command within the same directory:
   `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
   After that, poweroff (not reboot) your laptop, and boot it up again.
2. Wait for the fix to be released in Utopic (and subscribe to the bug so you will be notified), then install the latest 3.16 kernel with the following command in your terminal:
    `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic`
3. Wait for 14.04.2, which will use the 3.16 kernel by default.

Good luck.

Comment: It is not real difficult to fix ` uname -a
Linux jeremy-Lenovo-G710 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jeremy@jeremy-Lenovo-G710 ~ $ modinfo ath3k | grep 3408
alias:          usb:v13D3p3408d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
`  I did see that the fix should be in 3.16.0-29

Answer (score 0):

You could try this file to see if it will work
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0mxc8g98abuoxcx/ar9462-dkms_2.0_all.deb?dl=0